# MessageSource and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer cannot load messages but with classpath*

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, classpath

My applicationContext.xml is in path:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring
```

and property files are in path:

```
src/main/resources/messages
```

and I load spring context in web.xml as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

when I am configuring MessageSource and `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` as follows:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:messages/apps.properties</value>        
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:messages/ValidationMessages</value>
            <value>classpath:messages/app</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

they both don't work, it only works when I change `classpath` to `classpath*`
Any ideas why?

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work, is there some kind of error message when you start your server?

Comment: are you properties in the same `jar`? Did you try `classpath:/messages/apps.properties`. notice the forward slash before `messages`

Comment: @Jsword: Set a breakpoint in ClassPathResource.class (in the constructors) and start your servlet container in debug mode. Then, when Spring creates the Resource objects for these files which cannnot be found, check which ClassLoader is being used, which Path and which Class is used for the resolution. 

@tolitius: When using `classpath:` scheme, Spring strips off the leading slash anyway. See ClassPathResource( String, ClassLoader) constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html):

> 4.7.2.2 The classpath*: prefix
>
> [...] location string may use the special `classpath*:` prefix: [...]
>
> This special prefix specifies that all classpath resources that match the given name must be obtained [...], **and then merged** to form the final application context definition.

Are you sure there are no other `messages/apps.properties` files on your CLASSPATH coincidentally taking precedence and overriding your file? This description suggests that you might have several same named files that are merged when `*` is used.

Can you check this by calling:

```
SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResources("/messages/apps.properties");
```

?

Comment: thanks for feedback, but the url had to start without slash, and the resulted enumeration contains only one file in target/classes/messages, so what do you think ?

Comment: Sorry, this was my only guess, hence no response.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this excellent [article](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2007/05/17/using-classpath-vs-classpath-when-loading-spring-resources/) for classpath v classpth* difference in regards to spring resource loading, I did some testing on your problem in my testing it worked whether i used classpath or classpath*

I am listing the code here about the test i did

- I created a this directory structure (META-INF/spring under src/main/resource) placed context.xml
- I am listing complete context.xml here

  ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
               class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
          <list>
              <value>classpath:messages/apps.properties</value>
          </list>
      </property>
    </bean>

      <bean class="prasanna.service.TestBean">
         <property name="appName" value="${appname}"></property>
       </bean>

  <bean id="messageSource"  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basenames">
       <list>
         <value>classpath:messages/ValidationMessages</value>
             <value>classpath:messages/apps</value>
         </list>
     </property>
      <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
  </bean>
      </beans>
  ```
- Listing for apps.properties

  ```
   appname=spring mvc app
  ```
- Listing for ValidationMessages.properties

  ```
    error.name=Invalid name
  ```
- TestBean is rather simple

  ```
      public class TestBean 
      {
          private String appName;

          public String getAppName() {
              return appName;
          }

          public void setAppName(String appName) {
              this.appName = appName;
          }

      }
  ```
- I am using a simple java class to load the property files and read them

  ```
  public class LoadContext 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"classpath:META-INF/spring/context.xml"});
          ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource msgs = ctx.getBean(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.class);

                TestBean testBean = ctx.getBean(TestBean.class);
      Assert.assertTrue(testBean.getAppName().equals("spring mvc app"));

          String msg = msgs.getMessage("appname", new Object[]{new DefaultMessageSourceResolvable("appname")}, null);
          System.out.println(" "+ msg);

          String msg2 = msgs.getMessage("error.name", new Object[]{new DefaultMessageSourceResolvable("error.name")}, null);
          System.out.println(" "+ msg2);
      }

  }
  ```